# Difficulty accessing webview from broadcast listener

Tags: android, webview, broadcastreceiver

I would like to run a javascript function from a broadcast receiver, upon a heads up notification tap.  The receiver is registered in the manifest file.  Dynamically registering would not work.  As such the receiver class is static, so I cannot access the webview back in the MainActivity in order to webview.onloadUrl(js function).  Does anybody have an idea how to get around this?

```
Intent displayIntent = new Intent(this, DisplayReceiver.class);
displayIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
displayIntent.putExtra("anomaly_array", (Serializable) geoList);
displayPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, displayIntent, 0);

mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
...
.setContentIntent(displayPendingIntent);
```

The DisplayReceiver is an inner class of the MainActivity, and I need to run the webview in onReceive

```
public static class DisplayReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
....
webView.loadUrl(urlBuilder.toString());
```

Comment: What happens when you run `webview` in `onReceive`?

Comment: The webview.loadUrl is what I am attempting to run, I can't as it is showing up as inaccessible, since the class is static.  If i register the receiver dynamically, I never hit the onReceive

Comment: So basically you want to run a `webview` which is initialized in `MainActivity` right?

Comment: Yes that's exactly right

Comment: Could you try passing `webview` reference from `MainActivity` to `DisplayReceiver` using a `public constructor`?

Comment: Thanks again Michal, I actually tried that when I tried to dynamically register, this way the BR is non static also and can access the webview, however the web view is still null/not accessible inside the onReceive.

Comment: I managed to fix this issue.  It turns out you can use non-static classes with a receiver registered through the manifest.

Comment: What I did was set the webview in the receiver class, (pulled out of main activity as an inner class), I set the webview as a static field,  with a setter and then set it its value from the main activity,

Comment: DisplayAnomalyReceiver.setWebView(myWebView);